# How to read textContent of a div in the MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I want to read the textContent of a div and stor that value in a variable of c# server, to do further calculations based on it.

For example:

> View side

```
<div class="target" id="div1">
   <div>Start</div>
   <div>Process 1</div>
   <div>Process 2</div>
   <div>Process 3</div>
   <div>Stop</div>
</div>
```

> Controller side

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var list = /*Read the text content of the div1 */
   for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
   {
      switch(list[i])
      {
         case "Process 1":
         //do some tasks
         break;
         case "Process 2":
         //do some task
         break;
      }
   }
   return View();
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: First thing you need to do is understand the basics of MVC. Webform techniques are not going to work - you don't have direct access to the DOM server side. Start [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/asp-net-mvc-vs-asp-net-web-form).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.
After extensive google search, i found a solution with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I found this as a solution to my requirement:

```
jQuery.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "@Url.Action(<actionName>, <controllerName>)",
 dataType: "json",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 data: JSON.stringify({ <variableToSend> }),
 success: function(data) {
  alert(data);
 },
 failure: function(errMsg) {
  alert(errMsg);
 }
});
```